Why unknown identifier for a declared variable in Lean 4
I'm trying to follow the Introductory Proof with Lean 4 - Natural Numbers but I get unknown identifier 'b' and the same happens with all the variables except a.
I tried set_option autoImplicit false as suggested in Unknown Identifier issue in Lean 4 but that didn't change anything.
What could be the problem?

The code below works but I'm not sure why and the proof is not as readable
theorem T (a b c d e : Nat)
  (h1 : a = b)
  (h2 : b = c + 1)
  (h3 : c = d)
  (h4 : e = 1 + d) : a = e := 
  calc
    a = b := h1
    b = c + 1 := h2
    c + 1 = d + 1 := congrArg Nat.succ h3
    d + 1 = 1 + d := Nat.add_comm d 1
    1 + d = e := Eq.symm h4


a appears in your type signature, b doesn't.

You could include all the variables you need in your proof. Lean does not include variables and hypotheses by default if they're not mentioned in the theorem statement (which is another way of saying what Naim said)

@user454322 please don’t include screenshots (unless you also separately paste the code).  That way others can easily copy your code into the editor and verify the behavior you are seeing.

To convert Naïm and Kevin's comments to an answer:
Theorems by default only use variables which are in the theorem statement
The variable command in Lean is fairly lightweight.  If that variable appears in the theorem statement then it is added to the theorem, but not if it is used in the proof.  You can see this by #printing the theorem:
variable (a b c d e : Nat)
variable (h1 : a = b)
variable (h2 : b = c + 1)
variable (h3 : c = d)
variable (h4 : e = 1 + d)

theorem T : a = e := 
  calc
    a = b := h1
    b = c + 1 := h2
    c + 1 = d + 1 := congrArg Nat.succ h3
    d + 1 = 1 + d := Nat.add_comm d 1
    1 + d = e := Eq.symm h4

#print T
-- theorem T1 : ∀ (a e : Nat), a = e := ...

Note variables in definition (def) bodies do get added to the context, but again be careful, since conditions on those variables may not get added, like if you variable (x : Nat) (h : x > 0) and then def foo : x - 1.  foo will not by default have the condition that x is positive.
The include and omit commands change this behavior
As Naïm suggested, there are two ways you can control which variables in Lean 4 get added to the theorem: include and omit.  Here is one way to use include:
variable (a b c d e : Nat)
variable (h1 : a = b)
variable (h2 : b = c + 1)
variable (h3 : c = d)
variable (h4 : e = 1 + d)
include a b c d e h1 h2 h3 h4

theorem T1 : a = e := 
  calc
    a = b := h1
    b = c + 1 := h2
    c + 1 = d + 1 := congrArg Nat.succ h3
    d + 1 = 1 + d := Nat.add_comm d 1
    1 + d = e := Eq.symm h4

#print T1
-- theorem T1 : ∀ (a b c d e : Nat),
--   a = b → b = c + 1 → c = d → e = 1 + d → a = e := ...

But note if you do this, and later don't use one of these variables in a theorem, you will get a linting error (which unlike a type-checking error is logically ok, just questionable programming which may lead to errors).
A better way to is to use include ... in, which only applies include to the next theorem or definition.
variable (a b c d e : Nat)
variable (h1 : a = b)
variable (h2 : b = c + 1)
variable (h3 : c = d)
variable (h4 : e = 1 + d)

include a b c d e h1 h2 h3 h4 in
theorem T2 : a = e := 
  calc
    a = b := h1
    b = c + 1 := h2
    c + 1 = d + 1 := congrArg Nat.succ h3
    d + 1 = 1 + d := Nat.add_comm d 1
    1 + d = e := Eq.symm h4

#print T2
-- theorem T1 : ∀ (a b c d e : Nat),
--   a = b → b = c + 1 → c = d → e = 1 + d → a = e := ...

The omit command is similar but opposite, omitting the variable from a theorem.
Use section with variable
Also, it is good practice to put variables in sections so that you limit the scope of your variables.
Different from auto-implicit
You mentioned some related answers about auto-implicit and turning it off with  set_option autoImplicit false.  While I do recommend turning off auto-implicit for new users, nonetheless it is unrelated to your current problem.  What auto-implicit does is look for a variable in the theorem statement and if it isn't declared, then automatically add it to the theorem.  Since you already have the variables declared as variables it doesn't activate, and like variable, auto-implicit only applies to variables in the theorem statement, not the proof.
